# Scalars and forced callsite readability?

Tags: c++

I'm wondering what is currently the recommended way of disambiguating parameters and improving call site readability for functions by leveraging the type system. The trivial example is

```
int total(int price, int amount) {
  return price * total;
}
```

where it's hard to tell precisely what a call like `total(10, 2)`means, i.e. which parameter is which (in this case you don't get a bug if you mess up the order, because of commutativity of multiplication).

Basically, you can quickly do something like:

```
enum class ScalarTypeTag { PriceTag, AmountTag, TotalTag};

template<typename T, ScalarTypeTag K>
struct ScalarWrapper {
  explicit ScalarWrapper(T value) : value_{value} {}
  T value_;
};

using Price = ScalarWrapper<int, ScalarTypeTag::PriceTag>;
using Amount = ScalarWrapper<int, ScalarTypeTag::PriceTag>;
using Total = ScalarWrapper<int, ScalarTypeTag::TotalTag>;

Total ComputeTotal(Price p, Amount n) {
  return Total(p.value_ * n.value_);
}
```

This would then make it very difficult for the caller to mix up the argument order while at the same time being a zero cost abstraction as the compiler will optimize away the wrapping type. I'm basically interested in how to do this, so that it:

1. Minimizes the extra code needed by a user.
2. Makes it trivial to add new types (without mistakes)
3. Is a zero cost abstraction (compared to just replacing the types by the underlying types).

In the example above, I've on purpose introduced a bug by forgetting to change the tag on Amount to AmountTag after copy pasting, so Amount is actually the same type as Price, so we could still accidentally mess up the parameter order and the compiler wouldn't catch it. It would be preferable to minimize the chance of bloopers like this.

In other words, how to maximize the utility of this construct while minimizing the amount of caused annoyance?

UPDATE: Another problem is that this implementation would (probably, haven't checked) also prevent something like a copy of a std::vector of these to be optimized to a memcpy instead of a loop, so it wouldn't be completely zero cost.

Comment: It looks like this is a task for [boost-units](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_0/doc/html/boost_units.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
struct tag_t {constexpr tag_t(){}};

inline constexpr tag_t price{}
inline constexpr tag_t amount{};
inline constexpr tag_t total{};

template<class T, tag_t const* tag>
struct scalar_t {
  T t;
  constexpr explicit scalar_t( T tin ):t(std::move(tin)) {}
  constexpr scalar_t( scalar_t const& ) = default;
  constexpr scalar_t( scalar_t && ) = default;
  constexpr scalar_t& operator=( scalar_t const& ) = default;
  constexpr scalar_t& operator=( scalar_t && ) = default;
  constexpr scalar_t() = default;
  constexpr ~scalar_t() = default;
};

template<auto x, tag_t const* tag >
constexpr auto scalar = scalar_t<std::decay_t<decltype(x)>, tag>(x);

template<tag_t const* tag>
using iscalar_t = scalar_t<int, tag>;

scalar_t<int, &total> ComputeTotal( scalar_t<int, &price> p, scalar_t<int, &amount> n ) {
  return scalar_t<int, &total>( p.t * n.t );
}
```

callers can do

```
int x = 33;
auto total = ComputeTotal( scalar<7, &price>, iscalar_t<&amount>( x ) );
```

and pass in compile-time values or runtime values with a cast.

We don't do type aliases, instead we use pointers to tags for our tags.  Anyone can create a new scalar tag, and its constexpr address is its identity.

This allows distributed scalar type generation.